# while loop in Julia 1.5.3

Tags: while-loop, julia

Julia version：1.5.3

```
x=1
while x < 10
   print(x)
   x+=1
end
```

```
julia> x=1
1

julia> while x < 10
          print(x)
          x+=1
       end
123456789
julia>
```

[REPL result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m36pl.png)

[include result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gK2vJ.png)

```
x=1
while x < 10
   global x
   print(x)
   x+=1
end
```

[global include result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9H1wC.png)

Why is this code executable in the REPL environment, but the variable "x" needs to be decorated with "global" when I use the reference file "include"（“ test.jl ")", otherwise it will report that the variable is undefined?

I'd like to know why it works without "global" in the REPL environment

thank you

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)
Include your code/error as a [formatted code block](//stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) instead of an image.

Answer (score 1):

This is intended as described [here](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/variables-and-scoping/#Local-Scope) for user convenience. What you see is **Soft scope** (and [this table](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/variables-and-scoping/#man-scope-table) gives you information when it is introduced).

The exact rule is:

> if global `x` is defined, the assignment is considered ambiguous:
>
> - in non-interactive contexts (files, eval), an ambiguity warning is printed and a new local is created;
> - in interactive contexts (REPL, notebooks), the global variable `x` is assigned.

Finally [this part](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/variables-and-scoping/#On-Soft-Scope) of the Julia Manual explains in detail why such a design decision was made.

In general I would recommend you reading the whole [Scope of Variables](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/variables-and-scoping/#scope-of-variables) chapter in the Julia Manual.

Now it is worth to explain what happens with:

```
while x < 10
    print(x)
    x+=1
end
```

when `x` is treated as a local variable. Consider the following code:

```
x = 1
while x < 10
    @info "start"
    print(x)
    @info "middle"
    x+=1
    @info "end"
end
```

If you put it in a file and run it you get:

```
julia> include("test.jl")
┌ Warning: Assignment to `x` in soft scope is ambiguous because a global variable by the same name exists: `x` will be treated as a new local. Disambiguate by using `local x` to suppress this warning or `global x` to assign to the existing global variable.
└ @ D:\test.jl:6
[ Info: start
ERROR: LoadError: UndefVarError: x not defined
```

so you can see that what fails is `print(x)` because `x` is assigned to in a loop so `x` is considered a local variable and you try to fetch it before it is assigned to.

Now if you changed the code to:

```
x = 1
while x < 10
    @info "start"
    print(x)
    @info "middle"
    @info "end"
end
```

you would get an infinite loop (therefore please do not run it) as you do not assign to `x` inside the loop, so something like:

```
[ Info: start
1[ Info: middle
[ Info: end
[ Info: start
1[ Info: middle
[ Info: end
[ Info: start
1[ Info: middle
[ Info: end
```

is printed infinitely as `x` is fetched from the global scope (because it is not assigned to in the soft local scope).